# The action 'show' could not be found for UsersController when logging out | devise rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes

I've been struggling with something very silly here for some hours. 
No claptrap straight to the point. When I paste this into my posts#index page view file:

```
  <p><%= link_to "log out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %></p>
```

and click on it inside the browser, the user successfully signs out. However...

When I do this somewhere else like after the user has signed in or after the user has signed up, then the user tries to log out from a page which we can call users#index. 
It then only gives me this error upon clicking the log out button.

```
Unknown action

The action 'show' could not be found for UsersController
```

I've tried quite a lot of things, jquery and the jquer.uls or something are included in the application.js file,

These are my routes, and I think they're right.

```
Proxima::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :users
  resources :dashboard
  resources :posts
  authenticated :user do
  root :to => 'dashboard#index'
end
  resources :welcome
  devise_for :users
  resources :users
  resources :dashboard
  resources :posts
  root :to => 'welcome#index'
end
```

This is silly, I can't understand what's going on here, I get that silly message time after time and still no stuff happens. Then I decide to actually write down the action "show" inside the UsersController, however... When I write redirect_to welcome_path it doesn't log out, I check that by actually accessing the root url again... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You **need call in your view** the 'Unobtrusive Scripting adapter for jQuery' if use the jQuery.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery_ujs" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look into why your `:method => :delete` link is still ending up at the `show` action (an action to respond to GET).

With javascript set up correctly `:method => :delete` in a link_to should work fine, and go to the `#destroy` method in your devise sessions controller.

You can also try changing the default redirect path after a sign in/out here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-redirect-path-after-destroying-a-session-i.e.-signing-out

Answer (score 0):

If you have mistakenly removed

> //= require jquery_ujs

in your `application.js`

Answer (score -2):

So the error was:

```
Unknown action

The action 'show' could not be found for UsersController
```

So I went into the controller and defined the **show** action. Then i looked into some of the Devise docs and noticed this helper which I then used: `sign_out :user`. This was the temporary fix:

```
  def show
    sign_out :user
    redirect_to welcome_path
end
```

However that only logged the user out and redirected to the welcome_path, but then I got another error:

```
Unknown action

The action 'show' could not be found for WelcomeController
```

So I defined the **show** action for the Welcome controller as well:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def show
    render :index
  end
end
```

That redirected the user back to the root page. An voila! I then clicked on the login and button on the page and ended up seeing that I was asked to login to the page. I had successfully logged out and redirected the user back to the welcome index URL. Hooray! :D

However now comes the weird part. I don't understand why this works. So from the root URL when I place this code:

```
  <p><%= link_to "log out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %></p>
```

And then click on it after I've logged in, it successfully logs out without any extra writing into the Controllers or anything like that. Very smoothly and no work is needed, but when a user tries to log out from some other page and not the ROOT URL then it doesn't work and I get this error above with the **UsersController**.

I don't understand why the log out request asks for the show action in the **UsersController**. When it's a GET request to destroy the user session. I mean why do I have to specify to `sign:out :user` inside the controller when that is something which DEVISE is supposed to take care of. Please explain this behaviour.